# Given a position in a Grid, what row and column is it

Tags: c#, math, graph, matrix

I have an application I am writing where I have to place street addresses on a label sheet that is pre defined. This label sheet has 3 columns and 10 rows. I have the loop that creates the labels correctly, but there is a requirement to allow the user the ability to choose what label on the sheet to begin on. I would have thought this was going to be an easy mathematical matrix equation, but I am unable to come up with or find a solution out there.

Here is an example:

```
1   2  3  4  5
6   7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

Given the matrix above, lets say the user decides to start on #6. I need to be able to tell my loop to start at that location: col:1 row:2.

If it helps, The loop I have looks like this, but I think this comes down to a mathematical equation I'm not thinking of:

```
for (var yCounter = 0; yCounter < _labelSettings.LabelPerColumn; yCounter++)
{
    for (var xCounter = 0; xCounter < _labelSettings.ColumnsPerPage; xCounter++)
    {       
        foreach (var table in customNugget.PdfTables)
        {
            table.YPosition = SheetSettings.PageHeight -
                              (verticalOffset + yCounter * ((verticalSize + verticalOffset)));

            table.XPosition = horizontalOffset + xCounter * ((horizontalSize + horizontalOffset));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
     private static int _cellsPerRow = 3;
    private static int _startIndex;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        _startIndex = int.Parse(userInput);

        int startY = _startIndex / _cellsPerRow;
        int startX = (_startIndex - 1) % _cellsPerRow;

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The index you chose lives in the following matrix location:\n Row: {0} Column: {1}", startY, startX));
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }
```

Comment: can you not take the number divide it by the number of columns to get the row and use the remainder to move to the position of the correct column?  Hope I explained that well enough.....

Comment: Sorry Sorceri, Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are saying, but it worked with the number 9, but lets take the number 4. my Matrix has 3 columns, 10 rows ( or 30 labels possible), if I were to divide 30 by 4, I get 7.5. The column and row for 4 1 and 2 respectively, so this does not work.

Comment: you wouldnt divide it by rows but by Columns to get the row so 4/3 which 1 row and a remainder of 1 so one column over. I was explaining the same thing you accepted as your answer, just didnt do a good job at it apparently ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well assuming you know the number of cells in each row (which I think should be `_labelSettings.ColumnsPerPage`), you can calculate start values like so:

```
int cells = 5;//number of cells per row
int startAt = 6;//cell number to start at

int startY = (startAt - 1) / cells;//1
int startX = (startAt - 1) % cells;//0
```

You can then use these start values to initialize your loops, however you need to be careful to ensure your inner loop only uses the calculated start value on the first run. To do this you can just reset `startX` after the first execution of your y loop. Like so:

```
for (var yCounter = startY; yCounter < _labelSettings.LabelPerColumn; yCounter++)
{
    for (var xCounter = startX; xCounter < _labelSettings.ColumnsPerPage; xCounter++)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    startX = 0;//reset so that the next execution starts at the beginning of the row
}
```

[Here is proof of the logic, though it is in javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/rgG3N/5/)

EDIT: The calculation for `startY` has been modifed to correctly handle starting with the last number is a row (Thanks to @Zach for pointing the error out)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wasn't able to get the fiddler to run ( I don't use it very often, so i'm not sure what I need to do passed click run), but I updated my question above with what I tried and sometimes it works, sometimes not. Did I miss something? When I input 11, I'm getting Row:3 Column:1 when it should be row 4 column 1 (or two if you start at 1 and not 0)

Comment: @gcoleman0828: My code works on zero based index, because this is what your loops appear to require. In your example grid of 3 rows of 5. Then 11 should be the 3rd row and the first cell. Which my code would correctly produce 2 and 0 (zero based). The JSFiddle requires you to open the console to see the output results (in chrome: CTR + SHIFT + J)

Comment: My mistake you are correct. I miscounted the rows. I was wondering why the columns were always right, but the rows were 1 off.. Lol.. Thank god it's Friday. That's all I can say! And yes it is zero based and @Tim's below is 1 based, so it won't do. Do you have any material or know of any on the web that goes over this sort of equations so that I can read up on it a bit and get learned in it? I think it has to do with Matrix calculations, but everything I researched did not uncover much ion this type of problem Thank you very much again

Comment: Am I missing something or is this answer wrong?  What if you start at a number that is a perfect divisor of the number of columns?  Let's say 5 for the example above.  The y will be off by one in this case.  You should get starty(row)=0 and startx(col)=4, instead you get starty(row)=1 and startx(col)=4

Comment: @Zach: Well spotted, I have updated my answer to handle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = num % grid width

y = num / grid width
```

num is the number to start at
% is the modulus operator (remainder after dividing)
grid width is the grid width :)

Answer (score 1):

This works with 1-based values, as you show in your question:

```
int _cellsPerRow = 5; //number of cells per row
for (int startAt = 1; startAt <= 15; startAt++)
{
    int startY = (startAt - 1) / _cellsPerRow + 1;
    int startX = (startAt - 1) % _cellsPerRow + 1;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}", startAt, startX, startY);
}
```

(e.g., "6: 1, 2")

Comment: Thanks Tim... Can you point me to any mathematical web site material on this subject so I can understand where you came up with that and how to figure out things like this out in the future? I like to learn instead of just copy

Comment: @gcoleman0828 the heart of it is `index / _cellsPerRow`, using integer division, and `index % _cellsPerRow`, using the modulo operator. You can look these terms up for more details, but basically I recognized (thanks to Ryxuma's solution) that these would give you the sort of row/column values you were after, but with 0-based inputs and outputs. Then I just added and subtracted 1 as needed (I printed out the whole list and looked at what was off) to get the values you need.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. I guess my question then would be why is 'y' division and 'x' is modulo?

Comment: Because `a / b` from `a == 0` (incrementing `a`) will return `0` repeated `b` times, then `1` `b` times, etc. Which just happens to be the same thing you'd count off if you counted the rows (`y`s) from 0. And `a % b` from `a == 0` returns `0` through `b-1`, then loops back to `0` and starts again. Which just happens to be the same thing you'd count off if you counted the columns (`x`s) 0-based.

Comment: To put it another way: if multiplying `a * b` is to count the number of items in a rectangle that is `a` wide by `b` tall, integer division `a / b` is counting the number of whole rows when you arrange `a` items into `b`-width columns, and `a % b` is counting the number of items in the last non-full row when you arrange `a` items into `b`-width columns.

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach to this problem is to print the number to skip as blank labels. If you do not have the control as above, just generate your data with 6 empty labels. Works every time.

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET, if there is a 3-dimension array (matrix) with dimensions x(10,10,10), thus, 1000 elements, then the list of values i,j,k for each of the 1000 elements is:

```
  'k dimensions
  '10 elements per dimension
  '10^k total elements (grid size)
  Dim k As Integer = 3
  Dim elements As Integer = 10

  Dim perlist As New List(Of String)
  For i = 0 To elements ^ k - 1
      Dim str As String = ""
      For k = 3 To 1 Step -1
          str &= Math.Floor(i / 10 ^ (k - 1) Mod 10 + 1) & " "
      Next
      perlist.Add(str)
  Next
```

The above list is the list of permutations with replacement, i.e., n^r, or 10^3. Below is a screenshot of the first 20 elements (out of 1000):

[image]

To find the i,j,k values for e.g. array element 546, just look at the value of the string, str, using

```
 Dim str As String = ""
 For k = 3 To 1 Step -1
   str &= Math.Floor(546 / 10 ^ (k - 1) Mod 10 + 1) & " "
 Next
```